# keep ratio aspect webpage in mobile phone (overlapping)

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have some problems with my webpage when I try to turn the mobile phone in landscape mode. If it is in portrait, the webpage displays ok but if I try to switch, my buttons appear over the banner.

I have a banner for header and buttons in the foot (but all in body, diferents divs)

This is my code:

```
<body>  
<div data-role="page" id="home"  >
<div data-role="content">   
    <h2 id="banner">WebPage</h2>
    <div class="main_menu">
        <ul data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
            <li data-theme = "a"><a href="#button1">Button 1</a></li>
            <li data-theme = "a"><a href="#button2">Button 2</a></li>
            <li data-theme = "a"><a href="#button3">Button 3</a></li>
            <li data-theme = "a"><a href="#button4">Button 4</a></li>
            <li data-theme = "a"><a href="#button5">Button 5</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div> <!-- /main_menu -->
</div> <!-- /content -->
</div> <!-- /page -->
</body>
```

My css:

```
h2#banner {
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background:transparent url(icons/banner1.png) no-repeat left 10px;
width:146px;
height:162px;
margin:-10px auto -150px auto;
text-indent:-9999px;
}

.main_menu{
position:fixed; 
width:93%; 
height:0px;  
bottom:250px;
}

/* Home page banner landscape */
.landscape h2#banner {
background:transparent url(../img/banner/banner-landscape.jpg) no-repeat left 10px;
width:333px;
height:290px;
margin:-10px auto -175px auto;
text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

I want to keep the same distance between the banner and buttons in portrait and landscape mode or if it is not possible, keep the buttons below the banner in landscape but not overlapped.

Comment: try out with a media query.

Comment: I don't what that is, can you put an example?

Answer (score 1):

You should try out media queries. It's the best for mobile device when you designing a webpage. Or you should change every thing from margin, height and width of your elements into % instead of px.
Meid queries:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I just have to add media query restrictions to my elements in css files, don't I? And create new elements for others modes or screen sizes...

Comment: OK, I created a couple of css, one for orientation portrait(works fine) and other for landscape. But I don't know how to set properties for keep ratio.

Comment: just add properties like px cause you are using media queries it will only load that css file to that screen size